# Java -- Exception must be thrown, but how?

Tags: java, sql, exception

I am getting an error in  NetBeans saying I must throw an SQLException in this method:

```
private void displayCustomerInfo(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                     
{                                         
    int custID = Integer.parseInt(customerID.getText());
    String info = getCustomerInfo(custID);
    results.setText(info);
}
```

This method is created by NetBeans so it is not allowing me to edit the signature and throw the exception. This is why I created the `getCustomerInfo()` method. This method does throw the exception, because it uses a method to retrieve information from a database about a customer.

```
public String getCustomerInfo(int cid) throws SQLException
{
    Customer c = proc.getCustomer(cid);
    // get info
    return "info";
}
```

The `getCustomer` method also throws the exception and proc.java compiles.

The exact error is

```
unreported exception java.sql.SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

Comment: Forgive me, but why is everyone talking *just* about try-catch here? It is an option, but not the only option. Why can't the exception be thrown? 
Why wouldn't netbeans allow it? I don't use Netbeans (I use eclipse) but it sounds silly that an IDE does not allow to change generated code.

Answer (score 10):

In general, if your code needs to throw a type of Exception that the signature doesn't support, and you have no control over the interface, you can catch and rethrow as a type the interface does support.  If your interface doesn't declare ANY checked exceptions, you can always throw a RuntimeException:

```
private void displayCustomerInfo(java.awt.event.ActionEven evt)                                     
{        
    try
    {                                 
        int custID = Integer.parseInt(customerID.getText());
        String info = getCustomerInfo(custID);
        results.setText(info);  
    }
    catch (SQLException ex)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);  // maybe create a new exception type?
    }
}
```

You almost definitely want to create a new Exception type that extends RuntimeException, and have your client code catch that exception.  Otherwise, you run the risk of catching ANY RuntimeException, including NullPointerException, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, etc., which your client code probably can't handle.

Comment: I'll give you a +1 for having a correct answer that solves the problem, and may well end up being what the OP has to do, but could you please make mention that hiding things in RuntimeExceptions is generally considered bad practice? :D

Comment: Its considered a bad practice by some.  There are lots of cases where taking a checked exception (which should never have been in the java language according to some) and wrapping it in an unchecked exception is a good thing.  Hibernate does this in all cases, eg.

Comment: I've edited the answer to explain the issue more clearly.  I don't have a problem with RuntimeExceptions but I think it's probably worth it to make a new type so the client can at least know why the call failed.

Comment: In this case handling it is almost certainly better: write an error message using setText().

Answer (score 8):

Read the error message again, it gives you two choices.

You must either declare the exception as thrown (which you cannot do) or catch the exception.  Try the 2nd choice.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put a try/catch block around your call to `getCustomerInfo()`, like so:

```
private void displayCustomerInfo(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                     
{                                         
    int custID = Integer.parseInt(customerID.getText());
    try {
        String info = getCustomerInfo(custID);
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        // Do something with the exception
    }

    results.setText(info);
}
```

A couple good options for handling the exception might be: logging the exception and the details used to get it, or using it as a signal to retry the connection request. Alternatively, as Outlaw Programmer shows, you could re-throw the Exception as a RuntimeException of some kind, which removes the requirement of checking.

Answer (score 2):

It does not say you must throw it. It says you can catch it. So use a try/catch block and handle it.

```
try {
    ...
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("Exception happened! Abort! Abort!");
    e.printMessage(); //Not sure if this is the correct method name
}
```

Answer (score 1):

NetBeans generated components have un-modifiable code, and I'm guessing that it is generated as a part of the gui builder.  I'd ask if this was the case, but I can't comment yet.  If you select a generated object in the GUI editor, on the right there is a tab "code" that can be used to modify the grayed out area of the code.

Here:
[image: Code tab that is used to modify generated code.]

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this problem... been puzzled for the past 2 days.. then I open the source (.java file) with sublime, change the code, save, and it works wonders... I'm laughing when I see this works... think outside the box really works...

Comment: what did you change in the source file ?. Please mention the change, it will help others.